# Redirecting I/O in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode, io, arguments

I just installed Xcode 4 and I'm trying to redirect input from a file to my C++ program. I've tried using the usual "< infile.txt" in the "Arguments" section of my Run scheme, but that didn't work. I was able to redirect input and output in Xcode 3 just fine (by editing the arguments for the executable). Any suggestions on how to do this in the new version?

Thanks!

Samer

Comment: Xcode 4 seems to have a lot of teething troubles - unless you need to distribute apps via the Mac App Store then I'd suggest sticking with 3.2.6 until we get to at least 4.1.

Comment: In Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008), adding `< /absolute/path/to/input.txt` to "Arguments Passed On Launch" of my Run scheme also didn't work.

Comment: Update to Xcode 8

Answer (score 8):

I tested with various types of Arguments and it appears that Xcode have a bug with Arguments (last test: Xcode 8).

But there is one alternative to simulate with similar effect. You must use the Environment Variables.

Add a Environment Variable with the file name you want to redirect:

[image]

Then in your code you must "redirect" this file to the standard input (cin):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream arq(getenv("MYARQ"));
    cin.rdbuf(arq.rdbuf());

    string value;
    cin >> value;
    cout << value;

    return 0;
}
```

that's it... only 2 lines of code

```
ifstream arq(getenv("MYARQ"));
cin.rdbuf(arq.rdbuf());
```

it's not the best solution, but while xcode have this problem this is the only solution !

Comment: For the environment variable's value, type in the fullpath of the test.txt file (on a Mac you can simply drag a file into the space). This is still a valid solution as of Feb 9, 2017!

Comment: Please edit the answer to say "XCode 8" as this solution works on OS Sierra.

Comment: @Max thanks for the comment (and for testing it in Xcode 8) - updating the answer now

Comment: Thank you, I would like for OP to change the question topic to XCode 8 too.