# Command line input to user input in Xcode - C++

Tags: arguments

I have a program that works off command line input (argc and argv) but I don't know how to do that as I'm using XCode. Is there any way for me to get the command line input as user input in the program (e.g. cin the command line input through the program instead) and somehow convert that to argc and argv so I can run the main function which requires argc and argv?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your input from a file, you could make use of this solution:

[Redirecting I/O in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490175/redirecting-i-o-in-xcode-4)

Note that adding file input (< file.txt) arguments by going to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, choosing the "Run ..." scheme and then the "Arguments" tab will not work, at least not in Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: And by the way, don't expect me to learn how to improve my answers by receiving unmotivated down-votes.

Comment: Lukas's URL lead me to the correct solution, as of Feb 7, 2017!

Answer (score 0):

The 'xargs' command is used, in general, to convert a stream of data to argv-type arguments. I have no idea id there's a practical way to configure that in XCode.